how to print a specific text from an alert when there are multiple text in popup using selenium-JAVA?
how to print a specific text from an alert when there are multiple text  in popup using selenium webdriver-JAVA?
i tried with get text from alert after switching to alert. but there is an way to do it through indexing . but i am not able to get the correct solution

Try this way and also it so simple!
Once you get the text from the alert, you can use the java String functions to get the specific text.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
